# Why "die schlimmsten" and not "am schlimmsten"?

Tags: adjective, adverb, comparison

I’m having trouble understanding when to use *der/das/die* with a superlative and when *am*. I read [here](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Komparativ/Komparativ.html#der_am)

> Use a form of “der/das/die” with the superlative if it is right in
>   front of a noun.  Otherwise, use “am” with the superlative

Then, why is it *die schlimmsten* in the following [sentence](http://www.zeit.de/2013/43/portraet-fluechtling-aus-algerien/seite-2)?

> Die serbischen Polizisten waren die schlimmsten?

Should I assume that a noun has been ommited at the end of the sentence (“waren die schlimmsten [Polizisten/Menschen]”)? Is it because in this particular case, the verb is *sein*?

Comment: Don't know what your native language is, but that is in no way different from any other European language I know. --> The Serbian Policemen were the worst

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is totally right. The sentence just omitted the noun.

Both (Menschen and Polizisten) are right in that context.

Just to make it even more confusing: The sentence would be totally right if written as 
`Die serbischen Polizisten waren am schlimmsten`

Usually the form as chosen in the linked article is only used in a context of direct comparison and usually is not used on its own.

In that example they talk about "Ungarn", "Serbien" and "Mazedonien" and among all of them the `serbische Polizisten` were the worst. That's why it is written as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are half (or maybe three quarters ;) ) correct. In your example, there's is an implied noun. And the verb "sein" ("to be") has something to do with it, but in a different way.

You can use the superlative in two different ways: You can use it in an *adjectival* manner to further describe a noun. Or you can use it in an *adverbial* manner to further describe a verb.

In the adjectival manner, you have an article in front of the noun that's described further:

> Die roten Bonbons sind die leckersten Bonbons.

In English, that would be

> The red sweets are the tastiest sweets.

But in most cases you wouldn't repeat the noun, but shorten it in both languages:

> Die roten Bonbons sind die leckersten.
>
> The red sweets are the tastiest ones.

If you use the superlative in an adverbial manner, you have to use "am" in German:

> Der neue Kollege arbeitet am schnellsten.
>
> The new coworker works the fastest.

If the verb that is described further by your superlative happens to be "sein" ("to be"), the variants are similar and a bit confusing:

> Die roten Bonbons schmecken am leckersten.
>
> The red sweets taste the tastiest.
>
> Die roten Bonbons sind am leckersten.
>
> The red sweets are the tastiest.

but, as above

> Die roten Bonbons sind die leckersten.
>
> The red sweets are the tastiest ones.

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers fail to spell out: the difference between the forms *am schlimmsten* and *die schlimmsten* is that the former is an ad**verb** while the latter is an ad**jective.** Oftentimes in German grammar resources, I have seen the authors make no distinction between the two when they actually should because of the differences.

> Die serbischen Polizisten waren die schlimmsten.

In this sentence, there is **no implied extra noun.** It is merely an example of predicative usage of an adjective. Compare:

> Die kroatischen Polizisten waren groß.
> Die großen, kroatischen Polizisten …
>
> Die griechischen Polizisten waren größer.
> Die größeren, griechischen Polizisten …
>
> Die bulgarischen Polizisten waren die größten.
> Die größten, bulgarischen Polizisten …

This contrasts predicative and attributive usage of the corresponding adjectives.

The form with *am,* being an adverb, initially modifies the verb. However, in the case of *sein* being the verb, there is hardly any difference between using an adverb with *sein* or a predicative adjective. Compare:

> Die serbischen Polizisten bestrafen am schlimmsten.

Which is not equal to:

> Die serbischen Polizisten bestrafen **die Schlimmsten.**

This last sentence is *finally* an example where a noun has been left out; one could interpret it both as an ellipsed noun to be filled in with background knowledge or a nominalised adjective. In any case, it is important that in the final sentence *die Schlimmsten* can no longer refer to the policemen since *bestrafen* cannot introduce a predicative adjective. Instead *die Schlimmsten* must be someone else, e.g. *die schlimmsten Verbrecher.*

Comment: For protocol mostly, my answer does spell out the difference between adjectival and adverbial use ;)