# Why is the preposition required here?

Tags: preposition, superlativ

I attempted to translate this:

> The Master created humans first as the lowest type, most easily formed.

by saying:

> Der Herr hat Menschen am Anfang als den niedrigsten Typ geschaffen, der **das Einfachste** zu bilden ist.

But I was corrected to this:

> Der Herr hat Menschen am Anfang als den niedrigsten Typ geschaffen, der **am Einfachsten** zu bilden ist.

How is the addition of the preposition explained? Here are similar examples that did not require the preposition: https://bit.ly/3HLs84J

Let me clarify that I am concerned only with German grammar here, not with meaning. If the grammar is correct, in any context of meaning, then that would be satisfactory for my purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types and forms of adjectives in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71817/types-and-forms-of-adjectives-in-german) See also https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33021/35111

Answer (score 5):

You are intending a superlative in adverbial/predicative use  (so a lowercase initial letter is required).  The superlative is formed with *am*, as shown in examples (see e. g. [lingolia](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive):

- Friederike läuft am schnellsten. (adverbial/predicative use, as in your example)
- Sie ist die schnellste Läuferin (adjectival use).

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is the simplest thing. Not the simplest type of a particular thing. Although the English does contain the word, "type", it is referring to a thing in general. See: https://bit.ly/3HLs84J.

Comment: Your reference gives a nominalization, which is inappropriate in the example subclause. I can't recognize, what *type* should change in respect to grammar.

Comment: @user44591 The English text also uses the adverb *easily* which specifies the verb *formed*, not the type or the human. If you want this meaning you would have to write something like "...the easiest one..." (Of course the whole clause "most easily formed" refers to the type or the human.)